# using jquery focus to empty text fields

Tags: jquery, focus

I am trying to add focus on the following code, which would loop through the 10 or more fields and remove the default value(s)   when  the user focuses on the field.
how can i add the focus to the existing code?
-thanks

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#tradition').click(function() {
    $('#form-container').attr("class","trade");                         
    $('.lblMadlib11').text("Eleven ");
    $('.lblMadlib11a').val("eleven value field");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this markup this:

Html:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="default text" />
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){ // onload
    $('input:text').focus(function(){ // onfocus
       if($(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder')) // if value is default value
           $(this).val(''); // clear value
    });
});
```